# migrate database from old website to new WordPress website

Tags: sql, database, wordpress

I have a backup of the database from an old website that was created with WordPress. However, the client has requested the creation of a new website and the integration of the old website's database into the new project. The challenge is that I don't have access to the old website's admin panel; I only have the database backup. Is it possible to accomplish this task?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated <3.

Comment: By integration what does that means ? You have new website with some content and you need to add content from the old website ? Or new website that will use the same content from the old database ? If its first case you need to export the content you need and import it to the new one. If its the later one just upload the database under new name and thats all.

Comment: Yes, I have a new website and I need all the content from the old website. I only have the old website database backup. And I need to insert it into the new site's database. Sorry if I was confusing trying to explain.

Comment: Then upload the old database under new name. Fix your config file wp-config.php to point to that database. Fix in the "old" new databse url in wp_options table to point to the new domain

Comment: Thank you, you helped me. I'll try it this way :)